# Subobjects Equivalent iff Isomorphic Domains?

Tags: category-theory

Regarding subobjects as monics (not as equivalence classes of monics), I seem to have proven that subobjects are equivalent iff their domains are isomorphic as objects of the category in question. Since I haven't read this anywhere, I wanted to confirm - is this true?

Comment: This is false. Try coming up with two non-isomorphic subobjects $1 \to 2$ in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake in my "proof" aswell now. Thanks.